# Watin can't select an option from a select list

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, watin

I am using WATIN to complete a dynamically created form, which can contain several SelectLists (these are javascript controlled picklists). A sample of the select list format outputted is;

```
<select title=" " style="width: 300px;" 
    name="NameHere" 
    data-bind="value: NameHere.AnswerCode"
    class="fieldInputElement pickList">
    <option selected="" value=""></option>
    <option class="answerTextWithNote" value="A">alpha</option>
    <option class="answerTextWithNote" value="B" data-guidance="E.g. minor ">bravo</option>
    <option class="answerTextWithNote" value="C" data-guidance="E.g. b">charlie</option>
    <option class="answerTextWithNote" value="C" data-guidance="E.g. c">chatlie</option>
</select>
```

Unfortunately, watin seems to fail to select the list and any options, returning an error.

The code

```
window.SelectList(Find.ByName("NameHere")).Options[2].Select();
```

Returns an error about the index, although

```
string y = window.SelectList(Find.ByName("NameHere")).Option(x[1].ToString()).ToString();
```

will assign the correct value for the indexed option.

Can anyone advise me on how to trigger the select, as i have tried on focus() and keydown all without joy.

The selectlist is using the 'Chosen' plugin, if this helps?

Answer (score 1):

The following is somewhat not pretty.... but... it works.

Using

- IE8
- WatiN 2.0
- NUnit
- Chosen example here: http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/jquery-chosen.php

I was unable to reproduce your index error; I can access the SelectList options by index without issue (see code below).  BUT... accessing them didn't help at as Chosen has its own presentation markup.

So, instead I worked with the Chosen HTML elements instead of the SelectList and things are working better.

```
[Test]
public void ChosenTest()
{
    IE myIE = new IE(true);
    myIE.GoTo("http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/jquery-chosen.php");

    myIE.SelectList(Find.ByClass("chosen chzn-done")).WaitUntilExists();  //Needed as sometimes the controls were not fully loaded; unable to get item not found exceptions once this was added.

    Console.WriteLine("ByIndex:" + myIE.SelectList(Find.ByClass("chosen chzn-done")).Options[3].Text);   //To show no index out of bounds error.
    //  Just for reference --> myIE.SelectList(Find.ByClass("chosen chzn-done")).Options[3].Select();  //Has no effect.

    string id = myIE.SelectList(Find.ByClass("chosen chzn-done")).Id;
    myIE.Div(id + "_chzn").Div(Find.ByClass("chzn-drop")).ElementWithTag("li", Find.ByIndex(3)).Click();
    myIE.Div(id + "_chzn").Links[0].Spans[0].Click();  //Needed or the SelectList-ish stays open.
}
```

Finding ByClass was done as the control IDs change on the example page.
The WaitUntilExists eliminated the intermittent failures.