# Select an option using Watin

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, watin

I'm attempting to select an item in the first asset selection pulldown from this [page](http://www.marketoptions.com/trading-platform/) using Watin but can't get anything to work.

This example link has practically the same control and the code works perfectly [Watin can't select an option from a select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203920/watin-cant-select-an-option-form-a-select-list)

However, attempting to apply the same logic does find the correct elements but nothing is selected. Please can someone help identify why this is not working?

```
[Test]
public void ChosenTest()
{
    IE myIE = new IE(true);
    myIE.GoTo("http://www.marketoptions.com/trading-platform/");

    myIE.SelectList(Find.ByClass("assetSelect chzn-ltr chzn-done")).WaitUntilExists(); 

    string id = myIE.SelectList(Find.ByClass("assetSelect chzn-ltr chzn-done")).Id;
    myIE.Div(id + "_chzn").Div(Find.ByClass("chzn-drop")).ElementWithTag("li", Find.ByIndex(7)).Click();
    myIE.Div(id + "_chzn").Links[0].Spans[0].Click(); 
}
```

Edit: It looks like the css styling is having some affect which is not allowing Watin to click or select the standard html control. I'll offer a bounty once allowed if anyone can produce a working test that will select an item from the asset pulldown and explain why the current code does not work.

Comment: to understand bit more  - you want to get the first itme == "AUD/CAD" get selected ?

Comment: I want to be able to select any item in the list either by value or index.

Comment: is that site not showing trading platform during some time of the day ? it shows now trading in binary right now , and the form with dropdown doent show up ? what's the secrete here ?

Comment: The platform is viewable Monday to Friday, I didn't envision I would still be stuck on this at the weekend after first posting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spent a while looking at this and think the problem boils down to the fact that you are using an ajax control which actually replaces the select list with dynamically generated html instead. In fact the original select gets hidden, which makes it problematic to change.

The way I have worked around this type of problem in the past is to use the ajax controls javascript API to set the value and then trigger it's methods by using Watin to execute scripts.

Here is my code:

```
IE myIE = new IE();
myIE.GoTo("http://www.marketoptions.com/trading-platform/");

myIE.SelectList(Find.ByClass("assetSelect chzn-ltr chzn-done")).WaitUntilExists();

// remove the currently selected value
myIE.DomContainer.Eval("$('td.assetControl select option').removeAttr('selected');");

// set the new selected value
myIE.DomContainer.Eval("$('td.assetControl select option:contains(EUR/JPY)').attr('selected', 'selected');");

// update the ajax control to refresh the UI
myIE.DomContainer.Eval("$('td.assetControl select').trigger('liszt:updated');");

// sit back and enjoy the view as you hopefully see the UI showing the value that you wanted :)
Thread.Sleep(8000);
```

Obviously you will need to change *EUR/JPY* to the value you want.

Also, notice that I am using *td.assetControl select* as the selector. This assumes it is the only select in this cell. The selector you are using actually finds 4 matches when I first tried this in the browser. So maybe that was causing some problems too. There is actually an id on the select you can use if you think it is likely to stay the same (it looks like it might be auto generated though)

Hopefully this will work for you! let me know how you get on.

Comment: p.s. I have a working sample, I can email you the visual studio project if you like.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much this works perfectly!!! The only thing I've added is `myIE.DomContainer.Eval(string.Format("$('#{0}').change();", element.Id));` to trigger the change event after selection change, where `var element = myIE.SelectList(Find.ByClass("assetSelect chzn-ltr chzn-done"));`. Thanks once again the bonus is yours.

Comment: Thanks, you've just doubled my SO ranking! Anyway, glad it worked for you!

Comment: Hi Rob... 
I was very near to it. I spend more then 4-5 hours but lastly fade up...
Good solution... appropriated. Vote up for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that javascript or jquery event is binded with that drop down. try using eval.

Find the link by class.

var link = myIE.Link(Find.ByClass("chzn-single"));

link.DomContainer.Eval("$('chzn-single').click();");

Try this link this may help
http://thecuttingledge.com/?p=328

Answer (score 0):

i use this codes for find select list and select an option in it

```
IE browser=new IE();
var slist = browser.SelectList(Find.ById("the id of select list"));
slist.Option(Find.ByValue("1")).Select();
```

Comment: your method does not work on the example I have given

Comment: do you want select country in list ? this select list have an id , you can find it by id and select an item in it by value. if i understand your question right , help you for give its answer

Comment: No I want to select the asset which is currency pairs, stocks etc. Look for the element names in my original code. Also, there is no trading at the weekend so the controls won't be availble until Monday.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to complicate thing like this, manually making the id by combing the strings etc.

I can't access the website you mentioned in your example but selecting a option from the select list should be fairly simple

```
        //Find select list.
        var option= browser.SelectList(Find.ById("sbxControlID2"));
        if (!option.Exists)
        {
          //log error 
        }
       //find it by inspecting the select list with fire bug or any other inspection tool
        option.Select("Select option value here");
```

What you need to put in option.Select("SelectValue"), you can use the firebug to check the value of the option from the select list and put that value in there

The following code i have tested to select the product type dropdown from amazon's website

```
        //Find select list.
        var option= browser.SelectList(Find.ById("searchDropdownBox"));
        if (!option.Exists)
        {
          //log error 
        }
        option.Select("search-alias=arts-crafts");//This select arts and crafts option
```

Comment: Normally I wouldn't chain the elements together but I did on this occasion to replicate the example link which contains the same control. The example in question uses css styling and jquery so standard selecting and clicking are not working. Your example does not work!

Comment: @ooo does Option.Select("assetPlatformSelect_0_354"); dont select a value, also that dropdown is having an id so you can find it directly by that

Comment: The only difference i see in this dropdown is the select options are grouped.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void ChosenTest() {
   IE myIE = new IE(true);
   myIE.GoTo("http://www.marketoptions.com/trading-platform/");

   var slist = myIE.SelectList(Find.ById("country")); 

   //for select France in list 

   slist.Option(Find.ByValue("FR")).Select(); 
}
```

Comment: Wrong control! It's the control labelled Asset: